# Flutter, Firestore, how to get each query at the same using await?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

What I am trying to do currently is below

```
//some uid lists..
List<String> uidList;
//some future functions..
List<dynamic> gettingUserFuntions;

void _funA() async{

 uidList.forEach((uid) {
   gettingUserFunctions.add(_getUser(uid));
 });
 
 await Future.wait([
      //this gets error
      for (var function in gettingUserFunctions)
            {
             function();
            }
           ]).then((data) {
             print("everything completed at sametime!");        
                });
 
}

Future<DocumentSnapshot> _getUser(String uid) async {
    DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot =
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(uid).get();

    return documentSnapshot;
  }
```

For example, suppose that 30 individual documents are each called. I want all of this to be done at the same time. And when everything is done, I want to run the next code.

await Future.wait([]); seems to have a fatal flaw when we don't know the number of functions.

Comment: `await Future.wait(gettingUserFunctions)`

Comment: actually it should be just: `await Future.wait( uidList.map(_getUser))` - no need for `gettingUserFunctions`

Comment: Just a note: each read will count towards the maximum free reads, and will incur charges afterwards. If you have a lot of users, this use-case will probably cost you a lot. More on [pricing](https://firebase.google.com/pricing).

Comment: @Riwen yup I know that but thanks

Comment: @pskink Future.wait (gettingUserFunctions) does not proceed at the same time, it seems that it is already executed one by one from the time of uidList.forEach((uid) {
   gettingUserFunctions.add(_getUser(uid)); }); How can I prevent this? I want to call the functions at once in Future.wait part

Comment: @pskink And how do you send parameters in await Future.wait(uidList.map(_getUser)) part? The _getUser function needs a parameter.

Comment: you do not need `gettingUserFunctions` at all, use `await Future.wait( uidList.map(_getUser))` instead

Comment: yes `_getUser` needs a param and this param is passed by `map` method

Comment: @pskink when await Future.wait (uidList.map((uid) {
               _getUser(uid)
                       })); error This function has a return type of 'Future<_>', but doesn't end with a return statement.

Comment: @pskink okay return _getUser(uid) solves this. The last thing I want to check is, does this really happen at the same time? (With a small list, The FireStore is too fast to test. I`m not sure it is happening same time) I want to do kind of Promise.all in javascript

Comment: sry I do not get it. _getUser(it needs uid argument) why are you keep writing without an argument?

Comment: run the code i posted, here you have `await Future.wait(i.map(mapper))` - notice that `mapper` function is called and the right parameter is passed - this is all done by `Iterable.map` method

Comment: if you call `map((uid) {....})` you are passing anonymous, artificial function `(uid) {....}`, but actually you dont have to do that since you can pass already existing function - `_getUser` in your case

Comment: @pskink I didn\`t know that syntax thank you if you don`t mind can you post it as answer so I will adopt

Comment: write a self answer then ;-)

Answer (score 1):

helped from @pskink

```
void main() async {
  var i = [1, 3, 5];
  print('start, wait 2 seconds...');
  var ret = await Future.wait(i.map(mapper));
  print('done $ret');
}

Future mapper(int i) {
  print('start future, i: $i');
  var d = Duration(milliseconds: 2000 + 200 * i);
  return Future.delayed(d, () {
    print('future done, i: $i');
    return 100 * i;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this example will help

```
main() async {
  await runFun();
  print("runFun end!");
}

runFun() async{
  for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
    await waitThreeSec(i);
  }
}

waitThreeSec(int i)async{
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));
  print("$i is done");
}
```

Output:

```
0 is done
1 is done
2 is done
3 is done
4 is done
5 is done
6 is done
7 is done
8 is done
9 is done
runFun end!
```

Comment: The OP wants the reads to happen concurrently. Your proposed solution does not achieve that.

Comment: Rather than seeing this happen at the same time, the await ends, the next await is repeated, and this is repeated.

Comment: @rounpaleum `await Future.wait( uidList.map(_getUser))` does not work?

Comment: @pskink I am testing right now that you suggested I think it does work I just upvoted you. I've seen your answers in many questions. your id is familiar. Thanks